# How does ICommand's CanExecute method work?

Tags: wpf, .net-core

I've looked at some examples of implementing `ICommand` and to me the following way is the simplest:

```
class Command : ICommand {
    public Func<object, bool> CanDo { get; set; }
    public Action<object> Do { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public Command(Func<object, bool> CanDo, Action<object> Do) {
        this.CanDo = CanDo;
        this.Do = Do;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => CanDo(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => Do(parameter);
}
```

and that's how I've implemented in my test app. In addition to the `Command` class I've the following class:

```
class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    string firstName, lastName, enabled;

    public string FirstName {
        get => firstName;
        set { firstName = value; Changed();}
    }

    public string LastName {
        get => lastName;
        set { lastName = value; Changed(); }
    }

    public string Enabled {
        get => enabled;
        set { enabled = value;  Changed(); }
    }

    public Command MyCommand { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Person() {
        MyCommand = new Command(CanDo, Do);
    }

    void Changed(string name = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    bool CanDo(object para) {
        if (FirstName == "test" && LastName == "test") {
            Enabled = "true";
            //Changed("Enabled");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            Enabled = "false";
            //Changed("Enabled");
            return false;
        }
    }

    void Do(object para) {
        FirstName = "first";
        LastName = "last";
    }
}
```

and in `xaml` I've these:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Person x:Key="person"/>
    </Window.Resources>      
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource person}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>

            <Button Content="Click" Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding Enabled}"/>
        </StackPanel>         
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

After launching the app, whatever I try to type in those `TextBox` gets deleted instantly if I call `Changed()` in the `setter` of `Enabled`. If I comment out the `Changed()` in `setter` and uncomment two `Changed("Enabled")` in `bool CanDo(object para)` it works as expected!

Shouldn't calling the `Changed()` once in `setter` be equivalent to those two `Changed("Enabled")` call in `bool CanDo(object para)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` in `Changed`:

```
void Changed([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName]string name = "") => 
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
```

This obtains the calling property name so you don't have to call `Changed("Enabled")` but simply `Changed()` in the setter.

Comment: If I take out the `Label` in `xaml` and remove the `Enabled` property, I don't need `[CallerMemberName]` there! I'd that initially, then without the `Label` I tried removing that and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @EmonHaque: What is your question?

Comment: How did it work without that attribute when I didn't have that Label and associated property?

Comment: I could type in those text boxes normally and the button got enabled or disabled with the result of `CanDo`

Comment: @EmonHaque: `new PropertyChangedEventArgs("")` indicates that all properties should be refreshed.

Comment: that's why my textboxes kept getting refreshed on key press and I couldn't type! Thanks, it works as expected with that attribute.