# What's the preferred way of implementing CanExecuteChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, icommand

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336820/how-does-icommands-canexecute-method-work) the code I'm working with, the only change I've made there is added `[CallerMemberName]` attribute in `void Changed([CallerMemberName] string name = "")` method like that. In an article yesterday, I've read that instead of doing

```
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged 
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
```

I could replace this part:

```
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
```

with a `;` and add a function to handle `CanExecuteChanged` in `Command` class like this:

```
    public void Evaluate() => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

and call the `Evaluate` method inside the `setters` of `FirstName` and `LastName` properties of `Person` class. I've tested the app with both `add/remove` and `Evaluate` and both works.

Which of these would be more efficient?

Comment: You should use the simpler form in most cases. However, in the above case, your custom code delegate event add and remove to a command manager so you probably want to raise events from that manager too so delegation would be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this piece of code

```cs
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
    remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
}
```

`RequirySuggested` event is required for proper work of `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested?view=netframework-4.8).

This method is used for invalidate the command bindings and update `CanExecute` for all commands. You did almost the same manually using `CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);` for your `Person` class. But for some cases `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested` is still needed, for example when you need to update command binding outside of `Person` class or from other ViewModel.

There is also existing SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586345/why-people-use-commandmanager-invalidaterequerysuggested-on-icommands) with different opinions regarding your question.

Comment: then obviously the `Evaluate` method is redundant and there's no point in having one such in `Command`class since it works fine with `add/remove`.

Comment: `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested` and `add/remove` will update all commands bindings, with your invocation you have to it manually all the time. First option sounds more convenient

Comment: now you have to call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested` everywhere where you would call `Evaluate()`. I dont see the difference.